Batch "%1" and path spaces
On Windows I made a file called mingw64_open_with.cmd and associated .sh bash files so that they open with it, the goal being to be able to double click .sh bash scripts on Windows to run them through MinGW. This is my .cmd script:
@echo off
C:\msys\usr\bin\env.exe MSYSTEM=MINGW64 c:\msys\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd $(dirname "%1") && "%1""

It runs perfectly as long as the path to the .sh script, which is %1 here, doesn't contain spaces. When it does I get this: c:\msys\usr\bin\bash: line 1: cd: too many arguments. Nothing I tried, such as doubling the " solved the problem, I don't know what to do.

I don't have Mingw64 installed so I can't test this, but since batch is processing that line first, it's reading "cd $(dirname " as an argument, then %1, then ") && ", then %1, then "". Since batch can't handle nested double quotes like bash can, you'll have to escape the inner quotes first with ^. Give -c "cd $(dirname ^"%1^") && ^"%1^"" a go and see if that works. You may have to use ^^ instead of ^.

For your particular task, you may find that just changing %1 to %* helps.

Try cd "$(dirname "%1")".

@SomethingDark with one ^ I still get cd: too many arguments and with ^^ I get bash: -c: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching )'@Compo It doesn't, I still get cd: too many arguments@RenaudPacalet I guess you're suggesting removing a pair of"` but then I'd unable to do the rest of the command.

Can you answer the question nobody has asked yet. If you intend doubleclicking on a bash script to launch mingw64_open_with.cmd, you need to tell us exactly the command which is running when you do that, and the method of implementation. We need to be able to reproduce your environment and result, in order to offer focused assistance.

@Compo it's the normal Windows thing when you associate a file type to a .cmd or .exe with "Open with...", the path to the file being opened is %1. So for instance if my .cmd file contains echo %1 it will print "D:\Virtual Machines\QEMU\QEMU machines\launch_vm.sh" when I double-click that file.
Edit: Problem solved, see the answer below, thank you all for your efforts.

You didn't answer my question. If you have made a file association for a .sh file, then when doing so, you must have entered the command to run on such an association. If you created instead a context menu type entry, (which IMO would be better), then you would have created a command to run when invoked. We need this command to be able to fully match your environment, and offer the most robust solution for you. Currently, even with the posted, and accepted, answer, our readers can only guess how to invoke the batch file, (which shouldn't even be required for this), in the same way as you.

@Compo I don't know what you're talking about, that's not how "Open with..." works on Windows. .sh files are now associated with my .cmd script, that's all there is to it.

There is a command entry, it's not outrageous to ask what the entry is, or how you created it. Apart from that, why associate every .sh file with one batch file? What about creating a context menu entry with C:\msys\usr\bin\env.exe as the executable and your parameters and arguments added to it?

This works for me:
C:\msys\usr\bin\env.exe MSYSTEM=MINGW64 c:\msys\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd \"$(dirname \"$1\")\"; \"$1\"" sh %1


I confirm that this works for me too, thank you!
